# Zend Framework2 latest Review

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I previously worked on Zend Framework 1 the performance of it was fine.

I am about to start a new project in PHP I am planning to use Zend framework 2. 
But as I have seen the comparisons of ZF1, ZF2 on net. They are saying ZF2 was slow but the reviews was long time back. Recently Zend 2.0.6 was released on 2012-12-19.

Some one who used ZF2 please suggest me, can I go with ZF2 or ZF1?

I know this is like duplicate of another but i am looking for latest review.

Comment: Why don't you do it yourself? Set up both, create some benchmarks and share your results. I would prefer ZF2 due to its features.

Comment: The speed of a framework largely depends on what you do with it! There's no generally applicable benchmark for anything as diverse as a framework.

Comment: The `ZendSkeletonApplication` loads between 50-80ms. No Database calls, no MemoryCaching, nothing. A bigger Application of mine loads in roughly 150-200ms, still no caching or anything. Since i didn't use a single Cache so far, i'd argue that it's certainly 'fast enough'. I'm sure with things like APC i could get every request below 150ms, which is considered fairly good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will find that ZF2 will be much faster once you begin writing your application. Not only is ZF2 less bloated, but because it's not static based, you'll only be loading things when those items are actually needed.